# Howto install latest Oracle Java JDK (32-Bit) to Linux Xubuntu 14.04 (64-Bit) easiest way

Tags: java, 32-bit, jdk, javafx

- I have managed to install the latest Openjdk version of Java JDK via
  **:i386**    suffix so far.

  - But my JavaFX app depends on the Oracle JDK to run
    properly
  - I have only successfully installed the 64-Bit of Oracle Java JDK via **ppa:webupd8Team/java**
  - But how can I install the **32-Bit Version** of Oracle JDK?

I thank you for taking your time to read this message and trying to help me in finding a solution. Very much appreciated!

Comment: yes, it's kinda similar. I was reading other sources which confused me by telling to install some kind of 32-Bit Drivers first but those sources dated back to Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Check the link and if it doesn't work, explicitly mention in the question what didn't work

Comment: Hi Anwar, I have found this nice tool called Oraji https://github.com/neurobin/oraji. I just need to download this tool along with the latest 32-Bit JDK from Oracle. Then I start the tool and point it to the directory of the downloaded JDK .tar file and it does everything for you. Thanks for your help in guiding me to the right direction!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest solution I have found so far is using a great tool called **Oraji** which automatically does the configuration for you. Here is the brief excerpt from the install instruction created by the Oraji developer:

1. Download latest official 32-Bit Oracle JDK. File name should be jdk-... -linux-i586.tar.gz from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
2. Install Oraji on Ubuntu:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:neurobin/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install oraji
   ```
3. Java Installation Instruction:

   Run in terminal:

   ```
   sudo oraji '/path/to/the/jdk_or_jre_archive'
   ```

   or run

   ```
   sudo /path/to/oraji /path/to/the/jdk_or_jre_archive
   ```

   after giving the oraji script execution permission if you didn't install the script.

That's it. Now if you want to populate `JAVA_HOME` and other environment variables run `source /etc/profile` or logout and login.

For more info like Uninstall, Changing JDK version, just follow this nice tutorial by Oraji developers https://github.com/neurobin/oraji

Have a great day, guys!

Comment: In order to offer a solution on this site, you need to include the relevant parts from the link. We try to keep out content always accessible, and if a link in a link-only answer dies, then the answer itself is useless.

Comment: Good point! I will  include the relevant parts asap.

Comment: I've given a +1 hoping you'll put the relevant part soon. I'll check later :)

Comment: @Anwar thank you! So far I  am having a good time with the Ubuntu community! I have included the important parts. Have a good one!

Comment: @Anwar I really appreciate your cooperation for you taking your time to reformat the solution to make it become a much better reading experience! Nice :D